# How Can I Disable Touch of a parent element and enabale touch on child element using css and js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a modal so when I open a modal the parent element touch should be disabled and child element touch will work

I have done that for click using pointer events, but in mobile it behaves differently, is there anyway I can fix that for touch

```
<div className="parent">
  <div className="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

my CSS looks like

```
.parent {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.child {
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

is there anyway I can make my parent not scrollable also?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the [stopPropagation() Event Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_stoppropagation.asp).

Comment: it dosen't seem to work, my parent has some links and all work even with e.stopPropagation(